# Syncing feature between editor and pdf viewer not working

Tags: miktex, forward-inverse-search, texstudio

I'm using TeXStudio on Windows 7 with MikTeX. I don't know how to get the "Jump to source" command that appears in the mouse right-click menu, in the pdf viewer, once I compile a *.tex file with Quick Build. 
This feature is present and works well in TeXStudio under **UBUNTU 12.04**. How can I get it in Windows 7 too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add `-synctex=1` to the commands:

- `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
- `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
- `lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

After the next compilation there is a right-click menu item titled "Go to source" (Or shortcut `Ctrl+'`).

Comment: Hi Qrrbrbirlbel! That almost worked for me. In the haste I accidentally deleted the command that makes me open the pdf viewer automatically. What should I write after `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` for that to happen?

Comment: @WobbyWindows That has nothing to do with any `*latex` commands. Look under the configuration "Build", there should be an item "Build & View". Choose from the dropdown list. I think you want to have `txs:///pdf-chain` which is later defined as a combination of `txs:///pdflatex` and `txs:///view-pdf`. — Hopefully that is correct. I use a SVN version.

Comment: I went to _Options_ menu > _Configure_ _TexStudio_ >  _Commands_ and fixed it from there. I symply checked & unchecked the _Pdf_ _Viewer_ > _internal_ _viewer_ box and it took care of itself by offering me to add `-synctex=1` to the pdflatex command. All I did was click _Yes_.

Comment: Had the same problem like WobbyWindows (but on a Debian machine). Adding -synctex=1 to the pdflatex command worked for me as well. Regarding the option of checking/unchecking that WobbyWindows mentioned - I do not see that button in my version (2.5.2).

Comment: Also: latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: I am having the same problem as @WobbyWindows, though I have the options -synctex=1 in `PdfLatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Does this have to do with running Bibtex? Or is it because I'm running "Build & View"?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the option `-synctex=1` was in the command line. Yet it didn't work. What fixed it is deleting a file with the extension `*.synctex`. After that, syncing worked perfectly. Apparently, the file was a remnant of a previous latex compilation on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the option `-synctex=1` in the command line, but I generated the `.pdf` file and *all auxiliary files* on a different folder than the `.tex` file by means of the option `-output-directory=/some/different/directory`.
After having compiled, I had a post-compiling command copy only the `.pdf` back to the `.tex` directory.

The problem was that I had to copy also the **synctex** file (thanks to @FahadAlrashed for the hint). So, when on post-compiling I copied not only the `.pdf`, **but also** the `.synctex.gz` file to the `.tex` directory the synchronizing feature was again operative.

**Conclusion:** Be sure that the right file `.synctex.gz` (Linux) or `.synctex` (Windows) is at the same directory of the `.pdf` file accessed by the TexStudio pdf Viewer. :)